# Celery task not received by worker when two projects

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

My colleague has written celery tasks, necessary configuration in settings file, also supervisors config file. Everything is working perfectly fine. The projects is handed over to me and I seeing some issues that I have to fix.

There are two projects running on a single machine, both projects are almost same, lets call them `projA` and `projB`.

supervisord.conf file is as:

```
;for projA
[program:celeryd]
directory=/path_to_projA/
command=celery -A project worker -l info
...

[program:celerybeat]
directory=/path_to_projA/
command=celery -A project beat -l info
...

; For projB
[program:celerydB]
directory=/path_to_projB/
command=celery -A project worker -l info
...

[program:celerybeatB]
directory=/path_to_projB/
command=celery -A project beat -l info
...
```

The issue is, I am creating tasks through a loop and only one task is received from `celeryd` of `projA`, and remaining task are not in received (or could be received by `celeryd` of `projB`).

But when I stop celery programs for `projB` everything works well. *Please note,* the actual name of django-app is project hence celery -A project worker/beat -l info.

Please bare, I am new to celery, any help is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Are you using same broker for both projects? Looks like that is the issue here. Try to use separate brokers for both.

Comment: Please provide your celery settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Celery docs says,

> Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing.

When multiple tasks are created through a loop, tasks are evenly distributed to two different workers ie worker of `projA` and worker of `projB` since your workers are same.

If projects are similar or as you mentioned almost same, you can use `Celery Queue` but of course your queues across projects should be different.
Celery Docs for the same is provided [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html).

You need to set `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE`, `CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY` and `CELERY_QUEUES` 
 in your settings.py file.

And your `supervisor.conf` file needs queue name in the commands line for all the programs.

For Ex: `command=celery -A project beat -l info -Q <queue_name>`

And that should work, based on my experience.

Comment: Thanks, I did ended up using Queue but did not update the question. My Bad. But answer is similar to what I used.